# How to create an HTML page with dividers like this

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a webpage which looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYEis.png

I can't use frames(I'll be using AJAX on the site so more reason to have everything in one page because content on one page influences others. What's the cleanest way to do something like this?

A website which does something similar would be Google Reader. I'm a total noob with HTML and I'm not sure how they accomplished that.

EDIT: the sections should take up the entire browser window (so there is no scrolling down on the page, just individual sections. Google Reader is a good example of this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/C7eA8/. Note you will get problems using prozentual width and border on the same element. To get pixel perfect solution use width in px or draw the border to elements in the section divs.

Comment: Ah! Wonderful! Could you show me how I can include the header? (I updated the image above). When I try to do it, the page gets all messed up. Thanks!

Comment: Great this is awesome. One last thing - how do I make these elements take up the whole page?

Comment: @aerain: That's the inconvenience of using this code...the scrollbars are an inconvenience. This is why using a table is much simpler and easier to take care of, in my opinion.

Comment: also, is there a way to make these sections resizable by the user (horizontally  for all, vertically only for the one between 2, 4, and 3 since all of them should take up 100% of the screen). Thank you again for all your help :)

Comment: Ah! Thanks for your input Purmou - I was considering not using tables since I heard from html5 they are not liked as much as using div's. But i could be totally wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
<?DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .left {
        float:left;
        width:20%;
        height:500px; /* probably want to let content set height, though */

        background:#ccc;
    }
    .right {
        width:80%;
        float:right;
    }
    .right .top {
        height:200px; /* probably want to just let content set height, though... */

        background:#00f;
    }
    .right .bottom {
        height:300px;
    }
    .right .bottom .bottom-left {
        float:left;
        width:20%;
        height:100%;

        background:#ddd;
    }
    .right .bottom .bottom-right {
        float:right;
        width:80%;
        height:100%;

        background:#666;
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="bottom-left"></div>
        <div class="bottom-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually wondering if it would be possible to force show the scrollbars (kind of like what stack-overflow does to those code windows, etc). And I forgot part of my page. It actually should look like: http://i.imgur.com/HVKRB.png  (there's a header without the scrollbars). Thanks!

Comment: Give your elements static sizes then (`height: 300px; width: 20%;` or whatever you prefer) and then give them `overflow:auto;` - that tells the browser that if the content inside the element doesn't fit, it should use scrollbars to let the user see the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a layout like the page you want and set 
`overflow-y:scroll;` in the required div. That will work fine.

Comment: you can also use jquery ui plugin (layout) for better look and more customized functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using HTML's framset tag. The syntax looks like this:

```
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm" />
  <frame src="frame_b.htm" />
  <frame src="frame_c.htm" />
</frameset>
```

Read more about framesets here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp

**EDIT:** Oops, forgot you can't use frames. You should use tables to accomplish this, but I wouldn't recommend it. You'd use `rowspan="2"` to make that first cell span the entire height of the page, and a `colspan="2"` on that top right cell.

Comment: Sorry - I don't want to use frames (see above) or framsets. Thanks!

Comment: Can I get scrollbars like Google Reader if I use frames?

Comment: @aerain: But again, tables would definitely achieve this. I'd consider both options.

Comment: Thanks! I have to stick to a tables option, but I need to figure out how to force-show the scroll bars.

Comment: @aerain: Sorry for the comment confusion here...but adding this to the css for the cells that you want to force-show the scrollbars for would work: `overflow:scroll;`.

Comment: Oh ok...I think I get it. I'm still getting stuck trying to create a mock page like the image above using tables.....

Comment: This solution is like 1999. There are much better solutions instead of using franes or tables. You can simply arrange a bunch of divs and use oberflow-y:auto to force vertical scrolling.

Comment: @eskimoblood: I find tables somewhat easier to keep track of. Plus, like the example given in your answer, the divs don't always align. Tables allow this with ease.

Comment: @aerain: Here's an example of what you're trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/cDMe2/

Comment: Ah great. thanks purmou! it looks right. @eskimoblood what would you suggest instead of tables? I'm not sure how oberflow-y:auto and div's work....

Comment: @aerain: No problem. :) Also, eskimoblood's method just uses very specifically sized divs positioned next to each other. The `overflow-y:auto` adds a vertical scrollbar to the cell when the content starts to exceed it's size. Since you wanted the scrollbars to be there the whole time, I used `overflow-y:scroll;`.

Comment: @aerain: HTML really isn't that difficult. If you take the time to look through some simple tutorials, from beginner level to advanced, you could really learn a lot. Also, here's a useful jQuery plugin for resizeable elements on a page. Check it out: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Answer (score 0):

Everybody always disrespects my old-school tables. However, it is crossbrowser and it doesn't mess up the layout when windows width gets manipulated. Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/CPvTw/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>4 section demo</title>
        <style>
            html, body {height: 100%;}

            #global_table {border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

            #section_0,
            #section_1,
            #section_2,
            #section_3,
            #section_4 {border: 1px solid #000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;}

            #section_0 {padding: 20px 0px; height: 1%;}
            #section_1 {}
            #section_2 {}
            #section_3 {}
            #section_4 {}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="global_table">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" id="section_0">section 0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" id="section_1">section 1</td>
                <td colspan="2" id="section_2">section 2<div id="dragbar"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="section_4">section 4</td>
                <td id="section_3">section 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would add the scrollbars and dragbar using jQuery.

Comment: Wow this looks quite good, though I must say the code is much cleaner when using div's (and more html5ish)

Comment: Yes of course. However, try manipulating the width of the view box: http://jsfiddle.net/C7eA8/ as you see, the containers jump under each other. There for this is not the most optimal solution. My way does not look very neat, but is very much crossbrowser and very flexible.