# HTML division of space and resizement

Tags: html, space

I'm currently developping a Chrome extension (which means that I don't need a cross browser solution).

Basically, I want my web page to be separated into two parts. A left panel which would take 20% of the width and 100% of the height and a right panel which would take 80% of the width and 100% of the height. Those panels would contain various elements, textareas, list, select.

The issue is that I don't know how to achieve this and to handle resizement. Currently, I'm using jQuery with a window.onresize hook. I keep changing the width and height based on the window's size.

I want to know if that could be done in a simplier way, using CSS for instance. And what should I use? A div, a table, etc...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825774/how-to-create-an-html-page-with-dividers-like-this) earlier question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the existing panel, or element divs & spans inside a containing relative div. If
you use position:absolute for the panel divs, they will then be positioned
absolutely, relative to the containing div, not the page body.

http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 0):

Please adding css into your div, add `min-height`, and `max-height` properties

```
#mydiv{
 min-height: 700px;
}
```